# making the loop to continue to produce for outputs

Tags: python

Here is the code I have:

```
def generate(x)
    two = {}
    for x in range(1,7315):
        two.update({vowels[random.randint(0,4)] + alpha[random.randint(0,21)]:0})  
        return two      
generate(x)
```

this only returns a single value, how could I make it return multiple values?

Comment: `return` causes function to exit and stop. You can't make a function return multiple values.

Comment: Also, why are you using a dictionary for this?

Comment: What is the purpose of the function argument x?

Comment: Maybe you want to use `yield` keyword. Have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/231855/2932244).

Answer (score 0):

return a tuple with your values

```
def returnTwoNumbers():
    return (1, 0)

print(returnTwoNumbers()[0])
print(returnTwoNumbers()[1])

#output:
#1
#0
```

It also looks like you're trying to get a random vowel from your list of vowels. Using `random.choice` is a much more readable way to get a random item from a list:

```
import random
vowelList = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']

print (random.choice(vowelList))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tuple to `return` multiple values from a function e.g.:

```
return (one, two, three)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong indentation

```
def generate():
    two = {}
    for x in range(1,7315):
        two.update({vowels[random.randint(0,4)] + alpha[random.randint(0,21)]:0})  
    return two      

twos = generate()
```